# Determining two groups when only associations are known

Tags: clustering, binary-data, group-differences

DNA tests for genealogy provide the user with lists of people who match them on specific segments of their DNA. When 3 or more people all match each other on a segment, they form a Triangulation Group (TG), and the people are very likely to all come from the same chromosome (paternal or maternal) of the chromosome pair.

What I need to do is divide the Triangulation Groups into two, representing the two chromosomes.

All I have are the TGs, which is basically association data between the people.

Here's an example:

Let's say I have 5,000 people that I DNA match with. Each person will have on average 8 segments that are in Triangulation Groups, although they could have as many as 20 or 30. (Some could have 0, but I don't care about them.)  So there are about 40,000 segments in TGs associated with 5,000 people.

And let's say there are 1,000 Triangulation Groups, so each Triangulation Group will contain on average 40 segments belonging to 40 different people. Each TG could have as many as 200 segments/people or as few as 3 segments/people.

Therefore the problem is:

```
We have Person1, Person2, ... Person5000
We have TG1, TG2, TG1000
We have CHROMOSOME1 and CHROMOSOME2
```

TG[I] is a set of 3 to 200 people that are almost certainly on the same Chromosome.

We can represent this as a matrix:

```
SegmentMatch[TG, Person] = 1 if the Person is in the TG, 0 if not.
```

In most cases, one person's TGs will all be from the same chromosome. So the association of the people within and between the TGs can be used in some way. There will be some exceptions since siblings, nephew/nieces or double cousins could have some of their TGs on one chromosome (from one parent) and some on the other (from the other parent). This, however, should be a small percentage of the cases and should not prevent the problem from being solved. The best fit should do it.

The goal is to classify each TGs into two groups of chromosomes. In our example, this could turn out to be 600 TGs from one chromosome and 400 TGs from the other.

Is there a statistical technique that is best suited for this?

---

Here's a concrete example:

I have 11 Triangulation Groups and 881 people. In the table below, I'm showing the first 18 people. For each person, a 1 represents if they are in that TG and a 0 means they are not in that TG.

[image]

People tend to be in TGs together and I'm trying to split the TGs into the two groups that will keep the most people together.

One thing I can do is summarize the people who are in pairwise combinations of TGs. For example, the table below says there are 187 people in TG1, 176 in TG2, and 99 who are in both TG1 and TG2:

[image]

If I take each entry and divide by the minimum total of the two TG's (since no more than the minimum can match), I can get the following percentages:

[image]

I've highlighted in green the entries where more than 20% of the people who can match are matching between the two TGs. This would indicate that TGs 1, 2, 3,4, 5, 6, 7 and 9 have the most people in common between them and are likely on the same chromosome, and TG's 8, 10 and 11 are likely on the other chromosome.

It's not a perfect analysis. By this reckoning, TG 8 vs 9 should be less than 20%, and TG 8 vs 10 and 11 should be more than 20%.

My analysis only looks at pairs, but really n-tuples could be looked at, e.g. with my example data, Person 3 is in TGs 3, 5, 7 and 9. My analysis counted this as 6 pairs in the matrix rather than treating the n-tuples together.

What I'm looking for is a statistical technique or mathematical algorithm that will best classify these 11 TGs into two groups.